# Nesting pdfs - Prawn

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, prawn

Some context: I have some `html.erb` files I use to create a pdf using `WickedPdf` that I can make their own pdf or I can render in another pdf, but I'm switching to `Prawn` because `Prawn::Table` is more predictable with page breaks than `WickedPdf`.

I've got a few POROs that inherit from a `BasePdf` class that handles all the boilerplate pdf stuff like our company's header, font size, and access to the `@document` etc. Is it possible to have a `Prawn` pdf PORO that can be a pdf on its own like the rest of my `Prawn` pdfs but also be included in another pdf in the middle of a page (as opposed to starting a new page).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about prawn, but here https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_pdf/blob/master/docs/report_4.png an example of PDF with a table.

Also on the second page of PDF, it will contain table header which is good.

Comment: Prawn::Table already has support for tables and both Prawn and Prawn::Table have support for headers on each page

Answer (score 0):

We use extensively Prawn with plain Ruby or Rails to build complex business reports.

You can use all Ruby goodness to build reports like modules, class inheritance and custom methods. I thing this is one of Prawn's best part!

Each one of them can print/redner a part of a page or used as some kind of utility method. You actually right plain ruby that renders to pdf.

So you can have a base class with your company's lay out and custom modules which print some part of every specific report. Each module can take a hash with all required parameters for that module to render. This way you can also decouple reports from the rest of the app (that is db access etc.) and use or test them independently.